# Google Fit REST API returning old data points

Tags: python, flask, synchronization, google-api-client

I have a custom smarthome setup that is based on the Flask microframework.  I am currently trying to make a way to "sync" a wireless light attached to this network with the heart rate reported by my Huawei Watch 2 Sport.  I have no delusions that an actual live update of my heart rate is possible, but I have set my watch to poll heart rate every 5 minutes during the day using the Heart Rate OS app from the Play store.  I have cross-checked the Google Fit app on my phone as well as the Heart Rate OS app on my phone, and my watch is indeed reporting heart rate every 5 minutes.  The Google Fit app seems to be averaging data points within an hour or so, but that may just be graph layout settings.  However, when I grab data from the Google Fit service using the Google API Client, the newest data points I get in return have been anywhere from 12 to 24 hours behind.

I won't bore you with the details of the OAuth setup, but I have the credentials stored in the Flask session variable as a dictionary and just re-instantiate the Credentials object for each call to the heart rate endpoint.  Here is the code for the endpoint that retrieves heart rate:

```
@app.route('/heartBeat')
def heartBeat():
    credentials = google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials(
        **session['credentials'])
    fit = build('fitness', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
    print long((time.time()-60*30)*1000*1000*1000)
    dataSet = '*'#str(long((time.time()-60*30)*1000*1000*1000)) + "-" + str(long(time.time()*1000*1000*1000))
    print dataSet
    dataSource = fit.users().dataSources().datasets().get(userId='me', dataSourceId='A_VALID_DATA_SOURCE', datasetId=dataSet).execute()
    return str(dataSource)
```

As I said, I am retrieving data points using this code, but they are horribly outdated.  For this to even make sense, I would like to have readings that are at least within 15 minutes of present.  I don't really know why, but for some reason Google Fit is lagging somewhere in the process of sending my watch heart 
rate data from my phone's app to the online service.  Is there any way to force Google Fit to pull the most recent readings from my phone and watch?

Comment: dude found the answer ? even i have the same issue.